# How to retrieve selected data from Django Choice Field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to retrieve the `question_description` `answer_descritption` and `question_image` `answer_image` if found in the database according to topic and question type using two `ChoiceField` for both: Topic and Question Type.

However, I don't know how to do that. I have seen some tutorials and gotten glimpses of what I have to do, but I am not sure how to preform the same techniques on my case because online there are not that many `ChoiceField` examples, except that there are general examples on how to use forms and extract data from the database.

This is the `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from home.choices import *

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                    choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.topic_name

class Image (models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.image_file

class Question(models.Model):
    question_type = models. IntegerField(
                    choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
    question_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    question_description = models.TextField()
    question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.question_type

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_description = models.TextField()
    answer_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    answer_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is the `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
from .choices import questions_type_choices, question_topic_name_choices

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    topic_name      =   forms.ChoiceField(
                    choices=question_topic_name_choices,
                    widget = forms.Select(
                    attrs = {'class': 'home-select-one'}
                        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['topic_name',]
        def __str__(self):
            return self.fields


class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question_type =   forms.ChoiceField(
                    choices= questions_type_choices,
                    widget = forms.Select(
                    attrs = {'class': 'home-select-two'},
                        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_type',]
        def __str__(self):
            return self.fields


class QuizMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes    =   {
                'topics':TopicForm,
                'questions':QuestionForm
    }
```

This is the `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
from home.forms import QuizMultiForm




class QuizView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def get(self, request):
  # What queries do I need to put here to get the question and answer's description according to the ChoiceField input
        form = QuizMultiForm()
        return render (request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = QuizMultiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['topic_name', 'question_type'] # I don't know what to put here!

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render (request, self.template_name, args)
```

This is the template:

```html
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
      {% block content %}
            <form  method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.as_p }}
              <button type="submit" id="home-Physics-time-button">It is Physics Time</button>
              <h1> {{ text }} </h1>
            </form>
        {% endblock content %}
```

I would appropriate the help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cleaned_data` attribute of the form, contains a dictionary that maps the name of the field with the bounded data. And from the [MultiForm](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html) docs you can read:

> **cleaned_data**
>
> Returns an OrderedDict of the cleaned_data for each of the child forms.

Just extract data like this:

```
topic_name = form.cleaned_data['topics']['topic_name']
question_type = form.cleaned_data['question']['question_type']
# And so on ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

It is showing the `topic_name` and the `question_type` except when I add the others, such as: `question_description` and `answer_descripiton` it says:

`Key Error: 'question_description'` 

Could you please tell me why, and how to fix it.

Comment: In your forms, you have to add those to your `fields` list in the   Meta clases.

Comment: I have done that but they show up as input fields where I can type which is not what I want, I want the questions and answers in the database to show up.

Comment: You can use `froms.HiddenInput` for those fields.

Comment: I have used `forms.HiddenInput` on the fields that showed up and they are gone. However, it is showing `UnboundLocalError at /home/
local variable 'topic_name' referenced before assignment`

Comment: That would be another question in which I would very happy to try to help.